# Sql join on more than one record in same feild

Tags: sql-server

I want to make a join in sql to get class room details using the following tables:

table 1: `Student`

```
+----+------+---------------+
| ID | NAME |    SUBJECT    |
+----+------+---------------+
|  1 | ABC  | Science,Maths |
|  2 | XYZ  | Geo,          |
|  3 | XCZ  | Mar,Hin       |
+----+------+---------------+
```

table 2: `ClassRoom`

```
+----------+-----------+
| Subject  | ClassRoom |
+----------+-----------+
| Science  |         1 |
| Maths    |         2 |
| Geo      |         3 |
| Mar      |         4 |
| Hin      |         5 |
+----------+-----------+
```

I want the output to show all classrooms for respective subject e.g from first table Science,Maths should take differently

```
select * from [Student]

left join [ClassRoom]

on [Student].SUBJECT= [ClassRoom].Subject

Expected Output:- 
+----------+------+---------------+
| ClassRoom| NAME |    SUBJECT    |
+----------+------+---------------+
|        1 | ABC  |       Science |
|        2 | ABC  |         Maths |
|        3 | XYZ  |           Geo |
|        4 | XCZ  |           Mar |
|        5 | XCZ  |           Hin |
+----------+------+---------------+
```

Comment: How does your queries ouptut differ from your expected output. Do you have the correct number of rows? columns? correct data?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid There will be no output. His `[Student].SUBJECT` does not equal to `[ClassRoom].SUBJECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` statement

```
SELECT
    b.classroom, a.name, b.subject
FROM Student a
LEFT JOIN JOIN Classroom b 
    ON a.subject LIKE '%' + b.subject + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `LEFT JOIN` on both table fields with `LIKE` if they're any type of a `String`.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Student]
LEFT JOIN [ClassRoom] ON [Student].SUBJECT LIKE '%' + [ClassRoom].SUBJECT + '%'
```